# How to capture video + sound using Canon G7X Mark ii + Blue Yeti Microphone

Tags: audio, video, video-capture, microphone

Basically Microphone have USB port only.
Camera have micro USB looks like.

Are there is any way to record video and audio from those devices together?
Only one option that i see is capture separately one from another and after add sound on top of it.

But i afraid that it will be hard to fit video + voice to be look perfectly.

Any one have a solution for this? Or does anyone knows App which will help to combine them or edit video and adding audio on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Hand sync the video and audio.

Essentially, start the video, then turn the mic on. Clap a few times so you know where the two start when you go back to edit it.